# Import 'when' in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, when-js

Is there a way to make use of the *when* framework in TypeScript?

In JavaScript I can import it like this:

```
import when from 'when';
```

But doing the same in TypeScript leads to this error:

> Cannot find module 'when'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution'
> option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option? ts(2792)

I am using it to complete all the promises within a *then* clause:

```
.then(employeePromises => {
    return when.all(employeePromises);
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node' ? Did you even install 'when' with `npm install when` ?

Comment: "*set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node'*" - this seems to be the right way; however, I don't know how to do that (you should google on TS moduleResolution config)

Comment: What if using Promise.all([...]).then ?

Comment: Why are you using *when.js* instead of native promises?

Comment: While I agree with @Bergi that you should use native promises, it's worth mentioning `npm install @types/when`

Comment: It may also be worth double checking your .tsconfig, in case it's not looking in node_modules for when.js